# How to use Oracle Group BY in the below scenario

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Below is a very basic scenario.

I am finding it hard to understand how `GROUP BY` works even after going through a lot of examples.

In the below scenario i need to get minimum value of date and need to convert my query 1 to query 2.

query1:

```
SELECT b.aper07_req_created_s,
       b.aper06_req_status_k,
       a.aper06_req_status_x
FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b,
       iaper06_req_status a
WHERE  a.aper06_req_status_k = b.aper06_req_status_k
       AND b.aper07_req_k = 3387
       AND b.aper06_req_status_k = 4
ORDER  BY b.aper07_req_created_s
```

query 2:

```
SELECT Min(b.aper07_req_created_s),
       b.aper06_req_status_k,
       a.aper06_req_status_x
FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b,
       iaper06_req_status a
WHERE  a.aper06_req_status_k = b.aper06_req_status_k
       AND b.aper07_req_k = 3387
       AND b.aper06_req_status_k = 4
GROUP  BY b.aper06_req_status_k,
          a.aper06_req_status_x
ORDER  BY b.aper07_req_created_s
```

Query 2 is failing stating that its not a group by expression.

Can anyone help me in understand on how to get 2nd query right with some explanation?

Comment: Can you mark your SQL as code, and split it into multiple lines? Presentation matters, it will make it much more readable (thus more understandable for anyone that may want to help you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is with `ORDER  BY b.aper07_req_created_s`, try to replace it to:

ORDER  BY Min(b.aper07_req_created_s) :

```
  SELECT Min(b.aper07_req_created_s),
           b.aper06_req_status_k,
           a.aper06_req_status_x
    FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b,
           iaper06_req_status a
    WHERE  a.aper06_req_status_k = b.aper06_req_status_k
           AND b.aper07_req_k = 3387
           AND b.aper06_req_status_k = 4
    GROUP  BY b.aper06_req_status_k,
              a.aper06_req_status_x
    ORDER  BY Min(b.aper07_req_created_s)
```

ORDER BY 1 :

```
 SELECT Min(b.aper07_req_created_s),
           b.aper06_req_status_k,
           a.aper06_req_status_x
    FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b,
           iaper06_req_status a
    WHERE  a.aper06_req_status_k = b.aper06_req_status_k
           AND b.aper07_req_k = 3387
           AND b.aper06_req_status_k = 4
    GROUP  BY b.aper06_req_status_k,
              a.aper06_req_status_x
    ORDER  BY 1
```

You can also to use alias:

```
    SELECT Min(b.aper07_req_created_s) minemp,
           b.aper06_req_status_k,
           a.aper06_req_status_x
    FROM   iaper07_employee_offbrd_req b,
           iaper06_req_status a
    WHERE  a.aper06_req_status_k = b.aper06_req_status_k
           AND b.aper07_req_k = 3387
           AND b.aper06_req_status_k = 4
    GROUP  BY b.aper06_req_status_k,
              a.aper06_req_status_x
    ORDER  BY minemp
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions001.htm) you can find more informations.

Answer (score 2):

in your query 2, the `ORDER BY` clause is invalid.

After a `GROUP BY` (hence, in the `HAVING`, `ORDER BY` and `SELECT` parts), the expressions must be based either on the GROUP-BY columns, on constants, or on aggregate functions of the other columns.

You can use `ORDER BY MIN(b.aper07_req_created_s)` instead.

Comment: also now i found that i have to include "AND b.aper06_req_status_k = 4 " in having as this column is part of group by.

Answer (score 1):

To attempt to explain how `GROUP BY` works in SQL:
(I would say) it works in exactly same logical way you would expect it to work.
If you had a basket of fruits and you would want to get counts of all fruits you had by grouping type you would do:

```
SELECT groupingType, count(groupingType)
FROM fruitBasket
GROUP BY groupingType
```

If you use fruit type (apple, pear...) as groupingType then you will not be able to get fruit colour in your result simply because they (apples, pears...) can be of different colours. In a same way if you group by colour than you will not be able to get fruit type...